# Accuracy of GSL calculations (Ubuntu vs. Mac OS X)

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, amazon-ec2, clang

I am performing the same calculations on an Ubuntu instance on the Amazon EC2 Cloud and on my MacBook Air (newest OS). Since it is for academic purposes I make extensive use of the GSL library. The program is entirely written in C and is compiled with XCode on my local machine and with GCC on the cloud.
Right now, I am conducting a simulation study where I estimate a model, while knowing the results already. 
Is there a reasonable explanation why the results on my local machine are perfectly fine, but the produces less satisfactory estimates overall? Is there a difference in accuracy when it comes to use of the GSL library? I use the compiler flags `-O3 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm` in both instances.

Comment: Is the software the same? Are the versions of GCC, LibGSL, LibGSLCBlas, GlibC (and libmath but it's highly unlikely to be different from the one in the GlibC version installed). If the libraries were precompiled, have they been compiled with the very same versions of the very same tools? Does the problem still exists when you compile without optimizations (hard to come by, but `-O0` is a start)? (`-O3` is not necessary equal to `-O3`, it depends on compile time options. Try `gcc -Q --help=optimizers` to get some, sadly not all, information about it)

Comment: to be honest, I have no clue about the configurations. I just installed the most recent version of XCode and the GSL library which was available on the website. Likewise I installed GSL on the cloud like described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/490465/install-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-terminal). I can try it without the optimization flags but then I don't need the cloud anymore, bc the entire speed advantage disappears then.

Comment: switching the optimizations of is for test only. It is simple and done quickly and a start. But it is nevertheless one out of a long list of uncomfortable possibilities. Also: without the actual code with input and output and expected output it is nigh impossible to do little more than educated guesses. Can you at least tell how large the error/difference is?

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I will check compiling without optimization flags. It's hard to tell but for instance, one parameter is supposed to be around 0.8. On my local machine I get estimates between 0.7 and 0.9 which average on 0.8. In the cloud however I consistently obtain estimates around 0.6 only.

Comment: yepp, seems significant. I suppose it would ask for too much if you can compute that single calculation with another program and/or higher precision (I can offer an older Mathematica (10.0) if you have code for it but no license)? Oh, and do you use a random generator that you didn't write yourself? Some Monte-Carlo algorithms for example are quite sensitive to the kind of PRNG used. Also: when the results come in tighter it might be a case of higher precision, although I doubt it and that might even go in the other direction.

Comment: unfortunately it's about 10 files of C code... I use the mersenne-twister algo from the GSL package. Well, I guess I'll just run it on my local machine. But thanks for the offer!

Comment: What? Throw you rhands in the air and give up? That early? ;-) If it's `gsl_rng_mt19937` it could have a different seed (dep. on version, acc. to doc.), try setting it with `gsl_rng_set` explicitely.

Comment: I set the seed for `gsl_rng_mt19937`with the `gsl_rng_set` command already. The seed is always random based on the result of `time(NULL)`

Comment: Yepp, and there's the culprit, I'm nearly sure. I would propose to test with a fixed seed but that test costs money on EC2, so it's up to you.

Comment: I already have to pay for the instance so it doesn't matter. Is there a preferable random number generator? I used the `gsl_rng_taus` before. What do you mean by "that's the culprit"? Do you think that the randomness of the seed is the source of the error? Sorry for this long strain of comments but apparently my reputation on stackoverflow is not high enough to start a chat.

Comment: Lack of reputation? If that's all... ;-) but be warned: I'm really bad at typing!

Comment: Gnah! Only 19! Forgot that "good question" is only worth 5! Sorry. Yes, I think that it is not unlikely that it is the PRNG. A test would be to set the seed to a fixed value, or at least to repeatable values that you can set on both, the cloud and your Mac (e.g.: `0xdeadbeef` everywhere).

Comment: Okay, I will do that overnight. Do you think that the C language dialect has an impact? on the cloud I run it with gnu99, on my Mac it says `default`.

Comment: Yes, try to do everything as close to similar as possible.